# c++ runtime error working with if and else statements

Tags: visual-c++

So this program is suppost to tell you your grade based on the percent you entered and I basically only used if and else statements to code it. The program works all the way up to 59% and then when I enter in anything above that percent it doesn't work. As in the program just wont tell me the grade after 59%.THanks anything will help!!!

p.s. I know that there was probably a much easier way that I could have programed this but I wanted to practice if and else statements......

```
//
//exercise 1.
//you will enter in your percent and it will anounce your grade.
//create a program so that it will notify the user of their letter grade
//0-59 F 60-69 D 70-79 C 80-89 B 90-100 A
//a=user input
//For whatever reason the program seems to only work up to 59% and after that it doesn't work.



int a;
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
cout<< "Enter in the percent of your grade and \n I will tell you your grade"<<endl;
cin>>a;
if(a==100)
{
    cout<<"you scored a perfect A";
}
else 
    if(a<=59)
    {
        if(a<0)
        {
            cout<<"your really stupid";
        }
        else
            cout<<"you failed";
    }
    else
        if(a>=60)
        {
            if(a<=69)
            {
                cout<<"You got a D";
            }
        }
        else
            if(a>=70)
            {
                if(a<=79)
                {
                    cout<<"you got a C";
                }
            }
            else
                if(a>=80)
                {
                    if(a<=89)
                    {
                        cout<<"you got a B";
                    }
                }
                else
                    if(a>=90)
                    {


                            cout<<"you got an A";

                    }


}
```

Comment: I think your code objects to you using "your" instead of "you're". :) As for your actual problem, have you tried stepping through the code in debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are checking if a >= 60... which it is (suppose a = 75). However, it is not caught by any other conditional statements. Better explained by comments below in your code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int a;
int main()
{
cout<< "Enter in the percent of your grade and \n I will tell you your grade"<<endl;
cin>>a;
if(a==100)
{
    cout<<"you scored a perfect A";
}
else 
    if(a<=59)
    {
        if(a<0)
        {
            cout<<"your really stupid";
        }
        else
            cout<<"you failed";
    }
    else
        if(a>=60) // 75 >= 60
        {
            if(a<=69) // But 75 is > 69
            {
                cout<<"You got a D";
            }
        }
        // ONLY REACHES THIS POINT IF a < 60
        else
            if(a>=70)
            {
                if(a<=79)
                {
                    cout<<"you got a C";
                }
            }
            else
                if(a>=80)
                {
                    if(a<=89)
                    {
                        cout<<"you got a B";
                    }
                }
                else
                    if(a>=90)
                    {
                            cout<<"you got an A";

                    }
}
```

This would probably be a better approach:

```
int main()
{
    cout<< "Enter in the percent of your grade and \n I will tell you your grade"<<endl;
    cin>>a;
    if(a==100)
    {
        cout<<"you scored a perfect A";
    }
    else 
    {
        if(a<=59)
        {
            if(a<0)
            {
                cout<<"your really stupid";
            }
            else
                cout<<"you failed";
            }
        else
        {
            if (a >= 60 && a <= 69)
            {
                cout << "D";
            }
            else if (a >= 70 && a <= 79)
            {
                cout << "C";
            }
            else if (a >= 80 && a <= 89)
            {
                cout << "B";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "A";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing brackets after the first else.

Try this:

```
//
//exercise 1.
//you will enter in your percent and it will anounce your grade.
//create a program so that it will notify the user of their letter grade
//0-59 F 60-69 D 70-79 C 80-89 B 90-100 A
//a=user input
//For whatever reason the program seems to only work up to 59% and after that it doesn't work.



int a;
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
cout<< "Enter in the percent of your grade and \n I will tell you your grade"<<endl;
cin>>a;
if(a==100)
{
    cout<<"you scored a perfect A";
}
else
{ 
    if(a<=59)
    {
        if(a<0)
        {
            cout<<"your really stupid";
        }
        else
            cout<<"you failed";
    }
    else
        if(a>=60)
        {
            if(a<=69)
            {
                cout<<"You got a D";
            }
        }
        else
            if(a>=70)
            {
                if(a<=79)
                {
                    cout<<"you got a C";
                }
            }
            else
                if(a>=80)
                {
                    if(a<=89)
                    {
                        cout<<"you got a B";
                    }
                }
                else
                    if(a>=90)
                    {


                            cout<<"you got an A";

                    }

}
} // end main
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, as soon as you get to `if(a>=60)`, if the value of `a` is not less than 70, nothing is outputted, and the code exits the conditionals, because it has found a true condition. As to why you cannot get it to do anything at all above 59, I do not know, because it looks like it should work. However, by combining your inner if blocks with their parents, you can get the code to check for `a` to be within groups of 10 percentage points, and if it is not in that group, move on to the next. Below is an example of how you would do this.

```
//
//exercise 1.
//you will enter in your percent and it will anounce your grade.
//create a program so that it will notify the user of their letter grade
//0-59 F 60-69 D 70-79 C 80-89 B 90-100 A
//a=user input
//For whatever reason the program seems to only work up to 59% and after that it doesn't work.



int a;
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  cout<< "Enter in the percent of your grade and \n I will tell you your grade"<<endl;
  cin>>a;
  if(a==100)
  {
      cout<<"you scored a perfect A";
  }
  else if(a<=59)
  {
      if(a<0)
      {
          cout<<"your really stupid";
      }
      else
      {
          cout<<"you failed";
      }
  }
  else if(a>=60 && a<=69)
  {
      cout<<"You got a D";
  }
  else if(a>=70 && a<=79)
  {
      cout<<"you got a C";
  }
  else if(a>=80 && a<=89)
  {
      cout<<"you got a B";
  }
  else if(a>=90)
  {
      cout<<"you got an A";
  }
}
```